# Simple way to draw shapes in c++?

Tags: c++, drawing, geometry, shapes

Are there any drawing libraries out there that are really simple? I literally mean functions such as "draw_circle(screen,x,y,r,colour)" or something similar.

I've taken a look at SDL but it doesn't support what I want out of the box - I would like something that is really easy to use straight away, if possible.

Comment: if you're using WinAPI - then what about Windows GDI?

Comment: @Andrey I already mentioned GDI in my answer some time ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably Allegro5. It's easy and great for beginners. You can simply draw shapes and sprites.

[Allegro5 Website](http://www.allegro.cc/)

Answer (score 3):

You have a few different options here, depending on your platform. If you are on Windows for instance, you could use [Windows GDI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145203%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) or [Direct2D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd370987%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

But no matter what library you use, you'll have to deal with window creation and setup before being able to draw something. I think SDL is the easier way to go for beginners, besides, it's cross platform. Check this [resource](http://gpwiki.org/index.php/SDL%3aTutorials%3aDrawing_and_Filling_Circles) for a complete demo on how to draw circles using SDL.

Comment: Didn't Direct 2D die in DX7+?

Comment: @Robik I'm not sure we are talking about the same library, so I updated my answer with references.

Comment: @karlphilip You're right, i was thinking about DirectDraw. My bad.